# Can I use multiple booleans for conditional rendering in React?

Tags: reactjs, components, conditional-rendering

I want to do something like the following in a React component:

```
<div>
    {this.props.isOpen && this.state.isReady && <div> Hello! </div>}
</div>
```

Is it possible to use multiple booleans for conditionally rendering components in React? Could this ever possibly render a boolean to the user?

Comment: As @Sag1v points out below, you can do it, but I recommend that you don't since it is best practice to keep logic out of views, makes it more confusing to read, and will result in a page jump assuming the props and state could update, satisfy the condition, and then the `<div />` will appear out of nowhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it. it will either return the `jsx` or `null` (Won't render anything).

Example when condition is true:

```js
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {true && true && <div> Hello! </div>}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Example when condition is false:

```js
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {true && false && <div> Hello! </div>}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Can I have conditional rendering like `{true && true ? <Text>true</Text> : <Text>false</Text> }` ? I am trying but it shows me both texts

Comment: quick tip if you get something like this `{false && true ? <Text>true</Text> : <Text>false</Text> }` it will return text false but when you write `{false && (true ? <Text>true</Text> : <Text>false</Text>) }` (with brackets) it will return nothing. I wanted the second option and I couldnt understand why I get text false